# Python requests data in file, line by line

Tags: python, regex, request

I try to get the output of this request (https://api.opendota.com/api/players/7841909) in a file, line by line.

For some reason the output is stored in byte and not str, which I can change by str().

I tried to use a regualar expression to just store the information between the {} and also tried the csv module, which lead to just store digits.

What did I do wrong? The following version ignores the linebreak and the delimiters. :/

```
import requests
import csv
import re

dotaId = "7841909" #somit als string gespeichert
pfad = "https://api.opendota.com/api/players/" + dotaId + "/matches"

req = requests.get(pfad)

with open('%s.csv' % dotaId, 'w') as file:
    clean_line = re.findall(r'\{(.*?)\}', req.text)
    file.write(str(clean_line))
```

Comment: Is it json data? You should include a **minimal** example of the data, `req.text` - please read [mcve] When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question.  The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses.

Answer (score 0):

Your object clean_line is a list which you are writing as a one liner into the file.

It is better to use the csv writer module and write the content row by row:

```
with open('new_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, quotechar="'")
    clean_lines = re.findall(r'\{(.*?)\}', req.text)
    for line in clean_lines:
        writer.writerow([str(line)])
```